# How to debug xamarin forms app (ios ) in mac when visual studio mac retire in Aug 2024?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-code, xamarin.forms

Visual Studio for Mac will retire in Aug 2024. We recommend you use VS Code instead.HOW? does anyone share any documentation in how to debug ios simulators using vs code ? or what other tool will be available ?

Comment: Xamarin.Forms will go out of support as well, so you need to migrate your apps to MAUI eventually. There's a tool chain for Mac using recent .NET workloads and IDEs like Rider and VS Code. There's also a [VS Code extension for MAUI](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/visualstudio/announcing-the-dotnet-maui-extension-for-visual-studio-code/). However, you can still use VS for Mac even after August 2024, there just won't be any new versions or updates, so you won't be able to use the latest Xcode build tools, etc.

Comment: Use vscode and install the appropriate extension. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/mac/what-happened-to-vs-for-mac?view=vsmac-2022#alternative-options-for-developing-on-the-mac，  https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-dotnettools.dotnet-maui